# Передать типы данных из C# в DLL на С

Tags: c#, c, многопоточность, dll, marshal

Я создал веб-проект на `ASP.NET CORE` и к нему собрал и подключил библиотеку, написанную на `C`.

Чтобы использовать функции из библиотеки, необходимо определить в `C#` структуры данных. Со всеми типами данных разобрался остался вопрос с передачей двух типов, которые не знаю как интерпретировать.

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define thread_t    HANDLE
#define lock_t      CRITICAL_SECTION
#define initlock(f) InitializeCriticalSection(f)
#define lock(f)     EnterCriticalSection(f)
#define unlock(f)   LeaveCriticalSection(f)
#define FILEPATHSEP '\\'
#else
#define thread_t    pthread_t
#define lock_t      pthread_mutex_t
#define initlock(f) pthread_mutex_init(f,NULL)
#define lock(f)     pthread_mutex_lock(f)
#define unlock(f)   pthread_mutex_unlock(f)
#define FILEPATHSEP '/'
#endif
```

C# использует объект `lock` для блокировки потока и объект `Thread` для управления потоками, в `C` же это `CRITICAL_SECTION` и `WINAPI thread`.

Как мне передать эти объекты в C-DLL или отправить `CRITICAL_SECTION` и  `HANDLE` из C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HANDLE` = `*void`, в C# - `IntPtr`.

`CRITICAL_SECTION` - структура:

```
typedef RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION CRITICAL_SECTION;

typedef struct _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION {
    PRTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG DebugInfo;
    LONG LockCount;
    LONG RecursionCount;
    HANDLE OwningThread; 
    HANDLE LockSemaphore;
    ULONG_PTR SpinCount;
} RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION, *PRTL_CRITICAL_SECTION;
```

аналог в C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CRITICAL_SECTION {
    public IntPtr DebugInfo;
    public int LockCount;
    public int RecursionCount;
    public IntPtr OwningThread;
    public IntPtr LockSemaphore;
    public UIntPtr SpinCount;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сейчас попробую, если получится, то значит проблема решена

Comment: Вроде все собралось без ошибок. Еще не проверял как работает сама библиотека, но думаю все будет хорошо и это уже история другого вопроса на SO. Еще раз спасибо огромное!